# Oracle client encrypt connection to 11g, ignore 9i database

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle11g, client, tnsnames

I have two service names defined in a tnsnames.ora file and an encryption scheme in sqlnet.ora.

I'm using oracle instantclient, SQL*Plus 11.2 to connect to an Oracle9i server and an Oracle 11g.

I can connect to the 11g database, but get the error below when trying to connect to 9i.

```
ERROR:
ORA-12645: Parameter does not exist.
```

How can I specify the sqlnet.ora to be used only for the 11g connection?

**Edit:** Adding sqlnet.ora file. My understanding to make sure connection is encrypted is to set the client parameter to **requested/require**. But, anything other than reject yields the above error when connecting to 9i.

```
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=rejected
```

Connection to 9i successful, but I want encryption on the 11g connection!

Comment: can you post the contents of your sqlnet.ora